# Unable to configure muiltiple graphs on Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Trying to set Janusgraph Docker with Cassandra and ES as backend. When starting with following gremlin-server.yaml configuration it comes up properly and data gets saved in (janusgraph) tables in cassandra.

```
    `host: 0.0.0.0`
    `port: 8182`
    `scriptEvaluationTimeout: 0`
    `channelizer: org.janusgraph.channelizers.JanusGraphWebSocketChannelizer`
    `graphManager: org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager`
    `graphs: {`
     `  graph: conf/janusgraph-cql-es.properties`
    `}`
```

But when trying to set multiple graphs i.e. attempting to add ConfigurationManagementGraph in gremlin-server.yaml then getting error:

```
    graphs: {
      ConfigurationManagementGraph: conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties,
      graph: conf/janusgraph-cql-es.properties 
    }
```

Error message on docker restart:

```
    1130 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core  - DataStax Java driver 3.9.0 for Apache Cassandra
    1175 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility  - Detected Guava < 19 in the classpath, using legacy compatibility layer
    1538 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory  - Using native clock to generate timestamps.
    1722 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil  - Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
    2037 [main] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Could not invoke constructor on class org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphM
anager (defined by the 'graphManager' setting) with one argument of class Settings
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:91)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:122)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:345)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:80)
    ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:64)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:440)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:411)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:50)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.lambda$open$0(JanusGraphFactory.java:150)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.openGraph(JanusGraphManager.java:243)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:150)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:100)
    at 
    org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.lambda$new$0(JanusGraphManager.java:75)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.<init>(JanusGraphManager.java:74)
    ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    ... 18 more
    Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exception
s.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:268)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:107)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1813)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1726)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:214)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:387)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:366)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:311)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.initializeSession(CQLStoreManager.java:320)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.<init>(CQLStoreManager.java:182)
    ... 23 more
    5088 [gremlin-server-shutdown] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
    5092 [gremlin-server-shutdown] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the session OpProcessor.
    5253 [gremlin-server-shutdown] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
    5255 [gremlin-server-shutdown] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Shutting down OpProcessor[]
```

I have all dockers process running on same host and configured with ip 127.0.0.1. Need guidance to resolve this issue.

Thanking you in anticipation